# Should manual logservice flush work with automatic flush enabled?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, exception, logging, cron

I have a cron job sending email messages. In order to be within GAE quotas, after each email sent it sleeps for 8 seconds (`time.sleep(8)`). In result, the job runs more than 60 seconds and I get `CancelledError: The API call logservice.Flush() was explicitly cancelled` exception.

I've found the solution [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8809) and started to call `logservice.Flush()` manually after each message sent, but it didn't help. So, I am trying to understand the reason. Should I change `AUTOFLUSH_ENABLED` to `False` to use [manual flush](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/functions)?

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using the cron to fire off a task which sends the emails, then you have 10 minutes rather than 60 seconds to run the job.

Comment: This is exactly what I do. But still getting this `CancelledError`. Please have a look at the issue I am referring to - the first person is talking about cron job task also and having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, sleeping to reach quotas can be replaced with using task queues, and managing the queue rate, as explained in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue).

Comment: David, please see my comment at another answer - I already use task queues and get this problem there.

Comment: Hey LA_, my point is that you can remove the "sleep" instruction with Task Queues, and hence see if it removes your error.

If you tried that, please update the question to reflect that the emails are sent in a task queues and remove the reference to "sleep".

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong saying that I use task queue here. But this is cron job, so it has the same 10 mins limit. If I remove `sleep`, then an exception (API over quota) will happen and then, of course, I will not have that `CancelledError`.

Comment: The "API over quota" error happens because you are sending too many mails at the same time. Create a task queue, set the right rate according to the quotas, and create one task per email to send.