# CancelledError: The API call logservice.Flush() was explicitly cancelled - How to flush logs in gae to prevent this error?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, logging

I'm actually facing a similar problem to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212308/should-manual-logservice-flush-work-with-automatic-flush-enabled). My App runs fine for exactly 10 minutes but after this period has passed I always get this kind of error:

```
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 Traceback (most recent call last):
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/app_logging.py", line 79, in emit
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 logservice.write(message)
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice.py", line 391, in write
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 logs_buffer().write(message)
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice.py", line 1171, in write
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 return self._write(line)
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice.py", line 1188, in _write
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 self._autoflush()
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice.py", line 1256, in _autoflush
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 self._flush()
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/logservice/logservice.py", line 1239, in _flush
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 95, in MakeSyncCall
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 329, in MakeSyncCall
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 rpc.CheckSuccess()
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 134, in CheckSuccess
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 raise self.exception
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 CancelledError: The API call logservice.Flush() was explicitly cancelled.
E 2014-11-20 12:10:19.516 Logged from file wsgi.py, line 279
```

I'm calling a page by using a cron job. This page will then start a task queue (push). In here i tried to overwrite autoflush settings but couldnt reach any improvement.

```
import webapp2
from bdmodel import *
from indexObserver import *
import datetime
import indexObserver
from google.appengine.api.labs import taskqueue
from google.appengine.api import logservice

logservice.AUTOFLUSH_ENABLED = True
logservice.AUTOFLUSH_EVERY_SECONDS = None
logservice.AUTOFLUSH_EVERY_BYTES = None
logservice.AUTOFLUSH_EVERY_LINES = 100


class ClosingValueHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('<p>Closing Value</p>')
        taskqueue.add(url="/closing_value_queue")
        #result = detectClosingValue()
        #logging.info('detectClosingValue returned %s' % str(result))


class ClosingValueWorker(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        result = detectClosingValue()
        logging.info('detectClosingValue returned %s' % str(result))
```

Inside of this queue there is a recursive method that calls itself in case the final state hasn't been reached so far. As you can see i've already tried to manually flush the logs but without any effect. Does anyone know what to do? Thanks in advance!

```
def detectClosingValue():
    logging.info('detectClosingValue started')
    query = "SELECT * FROM DaxValue WHERE date = DATE('%s')" % str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
    q = db.GqlQuery(query)
    daxValue = q.get()
    if not daxValue.isTradingDay:
        return False

    else:
        previous = getLatestValue()[0]
        time.sleep(5)
        i = 1

        while i < 10:
            logservice.flush()
            logging.info("retrieved close %d value at %s" % (i, str(previous)))
            if previous != getLatestValue()[0]:
                time.sleep(25)
                detectClosingValue()
            i += 1
            time.sleep(10)

        daxValue = q.get()
        daxValue.close = getLatestValue()[0]
        daxValue.high = getLatestValue()[3]
        daxValue.low = getLatestValue()[2]
        daxValue.opn = getLatestValue()[1]
        daxValue.popDate = datetime.datetime.now()
        daxValue.put()
        logging.info("stored close value at %s" % str(daxValue.close))
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8809#c22), that error happens when a `DeadlineExceededErrors` is raised with logs in the queue.

If your app runs for exactly 10 minutes, try running it for just a bit less than that, for example 9:55 minutes, to allow the log to be properly flushed.